# Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression ( Im new to react.js so i cant understand how solve this error)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im getting the error (AS I COMMENTED OUT THE LINE CAUSING ERROR IN CODE ) in the following code as im in learning phase of reactjs this error doesnt make any sense to me. Guidance is required

```
componentDidMount() {
    let rooms = this.formatData(items);
    console.log(rooms);
  }

  formatData(items) {
    let tempItems = items.map((item) => {
      let id = item.sys.id;
      let images = item.fields.images.map((image) => {
        image.fields.file.url;     //  error is on this line
      });                         // The error suggest that its 
                                 // expecting an assignment or function
                                // but instead got an expression???
      let room = { ...this.fields, images, id };
      return room;
    });                 
    return tempItems;  
  }                    
                      
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <RoomContext.Provider value={{ ...this.state }}>
          {this.props.children}
        </RoomContext.Provider>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I suspect `items` is undefined in this line `let rooms = this.formatData(items);`

Comment: what `images` contains?

Comment: It is defined import items from "./data";

Comment: images: [
        {
          fields: {
            file: {
              url: img4
            }
          }
        } This. is the data im fetching and it is defined localy

Comment: so if you want to return url as object to images array the use this `({ image.fields.file.url })` or if just an url array not object the just return url `image.fields.file.url` do not wrap in `{}`, if you wrp in `{}` then use return keyword like `{ return image.fields.file.url; }`

Answer (score 1):

Currently the arrow function (`(image) => { ... }`) you're giving as an argument to `map` doesn't return anything. [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) require either an expression or a function body on the right-hand-side of the arrow. What you've written is a function body without a return statement, and thus `(image) => { ... }` returns `undefined` as default. You can either write the expression `image.fields.file.url` as-is to be the right side of the arrow (making the right side an expression instead of a function body) or add a return statement to the body.

That is, change

```js
let images = item.fields.images.map((image) => {
    image.fields.file.url;
});
```

either to

```js
let images = item.fields.images.map((image) =>
    image.fields.file.url
);
```

or

```js
let images = item.fields.images.map((image) => {
    return image.fields.file.url
});
```

Comment: ty for the help ^^